# Unable to execute a command in Psql from the Terminal

Tags: postgresql, unix, terminal

I'm trying to execute several commands in postgresql which I pay via the command line, but it returns the result from only the 2nd one:

```
psql -d data1 -U user123 -c "select count(*) from table1; select count(*) from table2;"
```

whereas when I login into "psql" and run the same commands, I get 2 result sets.

why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

`psql --help` gives (in part)

> ```
> -c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit
> ```

You have two **commands** here, to get both results you need to [combine the queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) (a `UNION`); like

```
psql -d data1 -U user123 -c \
  "select count(*) from table1 UNION ALL select count(*) from table2;"
```

**Or**, run two commands (queries)

```
psql -d data1 -U user123 -c "select count(*) from table1;"
psql -d data1 -U user123 -c "select count(*) from table2;"
```

**Or**, you can put both commands in a file and use `-f` (`psql --help` says)

> ```
> -f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit
> ```

Comment: @Karim re-read my answer: "-c" is a command line option to *run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit*; it runs one command and exits. The fact that it picked the second command may seem surprising, but it is in fact one command. Note the other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41375499/2970947) which omits "-c" and pipes the commands to `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe:

```
$ echo "
> select 1;
> \d
> " | psql # here is the magic, happy New Year *~<:o)
╔══════════╗
║ ?column? ║
╠══════════╣
║        1 ║
╚══════════╝
(1 row)

                List of relations
╔════════╤════════════════════╤══════╤══════════╗
║ Schema │        Name        │ Type │  Owner   ║
╠════════╪════════════════════╪══════╪══════════╣
║ public │ dummy              │ view │ postgres ║
║ public │ pg_stat_statements │ view │ nd       ║
╚════════╧════════════════════╧══════╧══════════╝
```